# Box2D & LibGDX: BodyEditorLoader error

Tags: java, json, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

I use the lastest version of LibGDX: 0.9.9! After have created a JSON file by Physics Body Editor 2.9.2, I try to load it in my game. So i wrote this in my code:

```
        BodyEditorLoader loader = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("data/myproject.json"));
```

But, when i run the game i obtain this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Searching in the web i have deduced that there is a difference between the JSON API of LibGDX (that was changed) and the Physics Body Editor JSON file generator, that is difference than the one.

Can someone help me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Just use a fixed file BodyEditorLoader.java than the original file available in the framework. (The file included in the framework is refered to a version of Physics Body Editor that has a different JSON API than the last LibGDX).

You can download the fixed BodyEditorLoader.java [here](https://box2d-editor.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=250013000&name=BodyEditorLoader.java&token=WiibMz3ulIIh_QnlIKLnOJQKta4%3A1390342800436)!.

Comment: Your link is not appropriate